# How I can check thumbnails youtube api

Tags: php, youtube-api

I tried check if maxres not exist then show standard and so on but if maxres not found not add any url why ?

```
$thumbnails = $vid["items"][0]["snippet"]["thumbnails"]["maxres"]["url"];
  if($thumbnails == ""){
    $thumbnails = $vid["items"][0]["snippet"]["thumbnails"]["standard"]["url"];
  }elseif($thumbnails == ""){
    $thumbnails = $vid["items"][0]["snippet"]["thumbnails"]["high"]["url"];
  }elseif($thumbnails == ""){
    $thumbnails = $vid["items"][0]["snippet"]["thumbnails"]["medium"]["url"];
  }elseif($thumbnails == ""){
    $thumbnails = $vid["items"][0]["snippet"]["thumbnails"]["default"]["url"];
  }
```

Comment: Hi welcome to stackoverflow in order for us to better assist you with your issue please try providing enough details that we can copy your code in our ide and test it for more information please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @CoderJoe I reading from Youtube API json I want to check if maxres object found not found in json then go to else if

Comment: Just looking at your code no links,explanations, nothing to help me reproduce the problem you are experience I have no advice to offer you other then improving your question. In thoery I should look at your question and be able to reproduce the issue that you are having if I can't then the question needs to be improved

Comment: @CoderJoe $youtube_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=" . $_POST["video_id"] . "&key=" . $key;

Comment: What is posted in video_id give me an example what is key

Comment: @CoderJoe get your api key from google developer console and get any video id on youtube

Comment: @CoderJoe new videos has maxers thumbnails but old videos like published at 2010,2009,2005 so on don't has maxers thumbnails in json

Comment: ok give me a few moments and I will test this please update your question with details to reproduce the issue so that others will know and the question wont be closed preventing me from helping you

Comment: @CoderJoe I don't know how to edit my thread , ok I'll wait you

Comment: @loppy for edit your question, press the [edit] link - which is below your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So several issues I noticed with your script the main problem being your if statement will enter the first loop and if it fails will never enter another loop

I have tested the below script on my server and found that it is working I hope it is clear to you if not I left comments

```php
<?php

function GetData($url,$post){
    $ch = curl_init($url . $post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
}

$res = GetData("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?","part=snippet&id=<video_id>&key=<your_key>");
$result = json_decode($res);

//Check for maxres thumb
$maxresThumb = $result->items[0]->snippet->thumbnails->maxres->url;

$thumbnail = '';

if($maxresThumb == '' || $maxresThumb == null){
  //if maxresThumb is not existent check for high res
  $highThumb = $result->items[0]->snippet->thumbnails->high->url;
  if($highThumb == '' || $highThumb == null){
    //Check for standard thumb
    $standardThumb = $result->items[0]->snippet->thumbnails->standard->url;
    if($standardThumb == '' || $standardThumb == null){
      //CHeck for next thumb....
    }else{
      $thumbnail = $standardThumb;
    }
  }else{
    $thumbnail = $highThumb;
  }
}else{
  $thumbnail = $maxResThumb;
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks but there is another way check below , thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

It's working now I changed to

```
$thumbnails = $vid["items"][0]["snippet"]["thumbnails"]["maxres"]["url"];
  if($thumbnails == "" || $thumbnails == null){
    $thumbnails = $vid["items"][0]["snippet"]["thumbnails"]["standard"]["url"];
    if($thumbnails == "" || $thumbnails == null){
      $thumbnails = $vid["items"][0]["snippet"]["thumbnails"]["high"]["url"];
      if($thumbnails == "" || $thumbnails == null){
        $thumbnails = $vid["items"][0]["snippet"]["thumbnails"]["medium"]["url"];
        if($thumbnails == "" || $thumbnails == null){
          $thumbnails = $vid["items"][0]["snippet"]["thumbnails"]["default"]["url"];
        }
      }
    }
  }
```